# @XmlElement name annotation ignored when unmarshalling xml to kotlin data class

Tags: xml, kotlin

I'm unmarshalling an xml file of type

```
<employee>
    <first_name>Jane</first_name>
    <surname>Doe</surname>
</employee>
```

into a kotlin data class of type

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType

@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = ["first_name", "surname"])
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class EmployeeData(
  @XmlElement(name = "first_name") val firstName: String? = null,
  @XmlElement val surname: String? = null,
)
```

using the following unmarshaller:

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext
import java.io.InputStream

val context = JAXBContext.newInstance(EmployeeData::class.java)
val unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller()
val data = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlContents) as EmployeeData
```

The `surname` field is correctly assigned the value "Doe", however the `firstName` field gets the value `null`, as if the `name` parameter of the `@XmlElement` annotation is being ignored.

The libraries used are the following:

```
implementation("jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:3.0.1")
implementation("com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:3.0.2")
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how it can be solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `data` classes, you need to explicitly specify that the annotation applies to the getters, otherwise it's going to use the variable name (which is why it works for surname without declaring `@field:`).  Since you are declaring that you are using field accessors,

Try

`@field:XmlElement(name = "first_name") firstName: String? = null`

instead

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, this is causing the following error: org.glassfish.jaxb.runtime.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There are two properties named "firstName". 
It seems the parser can no longer distinguish between the getter "getFirsttName()" and the value "firstName". Any clue on this?

Comment: I'm sorry -- I see that you have `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`.  I think  you can either remove that annotation and keep `@get:` or you can use `@field:` in place of `@get:`

Comment: Removing the XmlaccessorType caused other problems, but the @field annotation worked perfectly, thank you! If you add that solution to the answer I'll set it as accepted.